# Popup paypal payment window - how to send data back to main window

Tags: javascript, paypal

I've been using a paypal signup integration method where when you click on the sign up button it pops up a paypal login in a new smaller window. It is driven by the following...

```
<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
            <script>
                var dg = new PAYPAL.apps.DGFlow(
                {
                    trigger: 'paypal_submit',
                    expType: 'instant'
                     //PayPal will decide the experience type for the buyer based on his/her 'Remember me on your computer' option.
                });
</script>
```

The issue I am having is when the user logs into paypal inside the pop up window - it takes them to the 'success' re-direct page. Because the popup window is so small I have to use javascript to resize it and it's just a messy approach.

Is there a way for a successful paypal login, to close the popup window and redirect the original page the user was on to the desired account sign up page?

Answer (score 0):

Window management is not allowed from javascript for security reasons. Perhaps you could open the paypal window in an iframe?

That being said, it sounds like you are trying to resolve an issue that is already solved by oauth. Have you seen [paypal's "login with paypal"](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/) page?